# Tag synonym request: [dual-screen] -> [multiple-monitors]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

[dual-screen](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dual-screen) (3 questions) can be said to be a private example of [multiple-monitors](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple-monitors) (8 questions), so I suggest making the former a synonym for the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been done. Nicely spotted.